# where to publish essays about a life stories for personal development?

Tags: essay

I had a few experiences of things which I learned from some amazing people in my life. I would like to share some of these stories. The basic theme of these essays would be to follow your ambitions and to find balance in your life. I think that they are motivational stories for personal development.
Can anyone tell me where I could publish these essays? The specific names of journals/magazines/websites would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Medium](http://medium.com/) is probably what you are looking for. It is like [Twitter](http://twitter.com/), except instead of 140 character messages, you publish full-length articles, and instead of other users following you, they follow keywords that are like sections of a magazine. So you might tag your articles “inspiration” and Medium users who are following the “inspiration” tag will see your work. The advantage of Medium is it is easy to get started and there are already readers there at Medium to read your stuff. Another advantage is other website publishers read Medium and may want to syndicate your work if they like it.

Another option is to create your own blog, which you can do using [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/) or [Squarespace](http://squarespace.com/) or many other options. The upside is you can control the way your work is presented, but the downside is you have to drive readers to your blog, which can be challenging.

One thing to consider is a mixture of the two. Publish your articles on Medium, and also collect them on your own blog so that if (when?) Medium stops publishing, you still have your writings on a blog that you control. That gives you the advantages of both platforms.

Comment: thank you. I will look into medium. However i was looking for something i could put on my cv under the hobbies interest category, or under other publications. I published scientific  papers before, but i was wondering where i could publish something more related to personal development.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of (printed, non-digital) journals that publish non-fiction essays. [Poets & Writers](http://www.pw.org/literary_magazines) has a great list of them. ("Great" quantitatively and qualitatively.) I'll leave it to you to find the right one for yourself.

In addition, check your local newspapers: the big press and the alternative weeklies. Lots of them have columns that are open to reader submissions.

And if you want to keep them together as a collection, you can self-publish or contact a publisher that has a history of publishing similar pieces.